# Queryset Django - according to parameters date in weight compartment

Tags: django, model, django-queryset

I'm trying to get a result where my data from the database is sorted first by weight and then by date.

My models.py look like this:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(3)])
```

If I add in my object:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['-date_created ']
```

and in the queryset will filter out after the weight I get the result as in the picture below?

[image]

How to get such a result using only query, or only using the class in the models.py file? The picture shows what I would like to get.

Answer (score 2):

Just add another list element:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['-weight', 'date_created']
```

So first it will order by weight descending and then by date_created ascending.

More you can find in Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#ordering).